# Showing/Hiding a form with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, forms, hide, show

I have a form where I am trying to show and hide different input fields based on a user selection from a dropdown menu. I have it working in that when an option is selected, it shows the desired form, but hides everything around the form as well. If I set it to not hide anything and only show, it displays one form after the other.

What I am trying to do is set it so that when a user makes a selection, it displays the relevant forms without hiding anything extra, and if a user selects a new form, the new form is displayed and the old one hidden, all without hiding the pre-existing elements that are there from the beginning.

**HTML**

```
<section id="quote">
  <div id="quote_form" class="container border border-dark" style="border-radius:10px">

    <h2 class="text-center">Get a Quote!</h2>

    <form class="text-center">
      <div>
        <select class=" form-control-lg col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" id="building-type">
          <option selected disabled hidden>Please select building type</option>
          <option value="residential">Residential</option>
          <option value="commercial">Commercial</option>
          <option value="corporate">Corporate</option>
          <option value="hybrid">Hybrid</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tier_selection" id="standard" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="standard">Standard ($7,565/shaft)</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tier_selection" id="premium">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="premium">Premium ($12,345/shaft)</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tier_selection" id="excelium">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="excelium">Excelium ($15,400/shaft)</label>
      </div>
    </form>

    <!--RESIDENTIAL INPUTS-->
    <form name="residential" id="residential" class="text-center" style="display:none">
      <h4 class="text-center">Please enter the following information:</h4>
      <div id="residential_input">
        <div id="number-of-apartments" class="form-group form-field residential">
          <label for="apartment_number">Number of apartments:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="apartment_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-floors" class="form-group form-field residential">
          <label for="floor_number">Number of floors:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="floor_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-basements" class="form-group form-field residential">
          <label for="basement_number">Number of basements:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="basement_number">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!--/RESIDENTIAL INPUTS-->

    <!--COMMERCIAL INPUTS-->
    <form name="commercial" id="commercial" class="text-center" style="display:none">
      <h4 class="text-center">Please enter the following information:</h4>
      <div id="commercial_input">
        <div id="number-of-companies" class="form-group form-field commercial">
          <label for="business_number">Number of distinct businesses:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="business_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-floors" class="form-group form-field commercial">
          <label for="floor_number">Number of floors:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="floor_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-basements" class="form-group form-field commercial">
          <label for="basement_number">Number of basements:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="basement_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-parking-spots" class="form-group form-field commercial">
          <label for="parking_spaces">Number of parking spaces:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="parking_spaces">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-elevators" class="form-group form-field commercial">
          <label for="elevator_cages">Number of elevator cages to be deployed:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="elevator_cages">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!--/COMMERCIAL INPUTS-->

    <!--CORPORATE INPUTS-->
    <form name="corporate" id="corporate" class="text-center" style="display:none">
      <h4 class="text-center">Please enter the following information:</h4>
      <div id="corporate_input">
        <div id="number-of-corporations" class="form-group form-field corporate">
          <label for="companies">Number of separate tenant companies:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="companies">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-floors" class="form-group form-field corporate">
          <label for="floor_number">Number of floors:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="floor_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-basements" class="form-group form-field corporate">
          <label for="basement_number">Number of basements:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="basement_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-parking-spots" class="form-group form-field corporate">
          <label for="parking_spaces">Number of parking spaces:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="parking_spaces">
        </div>

        <div id="maximum-occupancy" class="form-group form-field corporate">
          <label for="people_floor">Maximum number of people per floor:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="people_floor">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!--/CORPORATE INPUTS-->

    <!--HYBRID INPUTS-->
    <form name="hybrid" id="hybrid" class="text-center" style="display:none">
      <h4 class="text-center">Please enter the following information:</h4>
      <div id="hybrid-input">
        <div id="number-of-companies" class="form-group form-field hybrid">
          <label for="business_number">Number of distinct businesses:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="business_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-floors" class="form-group form-field hybrid">
          <label for="floor_number">Number of floors:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="floor_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-basements" class="form-group form-field hybrid">
          <label for="basement_number">Number of basements:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="basement_number">
        </div>

        <div id="number-of-parking-spots" class="form-group form-field hybrid">
          <label for="parking_spaces">Number of parking spaces:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="parking_spaces">
        </div>

        <div id="maximum-occupancy" class="form-group form-field hybrid">
          <label for="people_floor">Maximum number of people per floor:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="people_floor">
        </div>

        <div id="business-hours" class="form-group form-field hybrid">
          <label for="active_hours">Building active hours per day:</label>
          <select class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6" id="active_hours">
            <option selected id="0" value="0">0</option>
            <option id="1" value="1">1</option>
            <option id="2" value="2">2</option>
            <option id="3" value="3">3</option>
            <option id="4" value="4">4</option>
            <option id="5" value="5">5</option>
            <option id="6" value="6">6</option>
            <option id="7" value="7">7</option>
            <option id="8" value="8">8</option>
            <option id="9" value="9">9</option>
            <option id="10" value="10">10</option>
            <option id="11" value="11">11</option>
            <option id="12" value="12">12</option>
            <option id="13" value="13">13</option>
            <option id="14" value="14">14</option>
            <option id="15" value="15">15</option>
            <option id="16" value="16">16</option>
            <option id="17" value="17">17</option>
            <option id="18" value="18">18</option>
            <option id="19" value="19">19</option>
            <option id="20" value="20">20</option>
            <option id="21" value="21">21</option>
            <option id="22" value="22">22</option>
            <option id="23" value="23">23</option>
            <option id="24" value="24">24</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!--/HYBRID INPUTS-->

    <!--QUOTE OUTPUTS-->
    <div id="quote_output">
      <h2 class="text-center">Your instant quote:</h2>

      <form class="text-center">
        <div id="quote_output_fields">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="elevator_number">Number of elevators:</label>
            <input type="text" readonly class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6 plaintext" id="elevator_number">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quote_total">Installation Quote:</label>
            <input type="text" readonly class="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-6 plaintext" id="quote_total">
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
    <!--/QUOTE OUTPUTS-->
  </div>
</section>
```

**jQuery that hides everything except selection**

```
$("#building-type").on("change", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

**jQuery that only shows, no hiding**

```
$("#building-type").on("change", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
})
```

**jQuery that I think will hide the old selection, I am just not sure what to put in place of "this"**

```
$("#building-type").on("change", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
  $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
})
```

Thanks for any help, if you need any other information I will try to provide it as soon as I can.

Comment: I have created  JSFiddle with your code
https://jsfiddle.net/euv5typz/

Try adding the code that I have missed. It will help in finding the solution.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh I looked at what you set up, and everything you entered is behaving how it is in my code, but i am not sure what else you would like me to add. I am not sure of the proper solution, or if my idea of having the line to show and the line to hide is correct. if it is, i just dont know what to put in place of "this".

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/qgzbpxve/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `sub-form` class on evey `form` that should hide/show...

Then this `change` handler on the select should work:

```
$("#building-type").on("change", function() {
  console.log("change",$(this).val())
  $(".sub-form").hide()
  $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qBaLmKL?editors=0011)

Comment: Yes, this works exactly the same as the code that i came up with as well, but it looks much better and is a lot less code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After some more looking around and playing with it, I did find a solution, though I don't think it is written as well as it could be, but it works.

**jQuery that worked**

```
$('#building-type').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="residential"){
    $("#residential").show()
    }
    else if( $(this).val()==="commercial"){
        $("#commercial").show()
    }
    else if( $(this).val()==="corporate"){
        $("#corporate").show()
    }
    else if( $(this).val()==="hybrid"){
        $("#hybrid").show()
    }
    else{
    $("#" + $(this)).hide()
    }
});
```